# Importing pdf file inside map function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have my publication list defined in JSON as follow:

```
[
    {
        "title": "Title 2",
        "authors": "Author1, Author2",
        "abstract": "Lorem Ipsum.",
        "year": 2021,
        "venue": "Venue",
        "pdf": "../../assets/1.pdf"
    },
    {
        "title": "Title 2",
        "authors": "Author 1, Authot 2",
        "abstract": "Lorem Ipsum.",
        "year": 2022,
        "venue": "CVPR",
        "pdf": "../../assets/2.pdf"
    }
    
]
```

I use map to create separate publication blocks on my website as follow:

```
import "./Publications.css"
import PublicationList from "../../assets/publications.json"

import {AiFillFilePdf} from 'react-icons/ai'
import {RiFilePaperLine} from "react-icons/ri"

const Publications = (props) => {

    return(
        <div className="section-container">
            <div className="container-row">
                <h1>Publications</h1>
            </div>

            <div id="publications-body" className="container-row">
                {
                    PublicationList.map(publication => {
                        return(
                            <div className="publication">
                                <div className="publication-text">
                                    <b>{publication.title}</b>
                                    <br />
                                    {publication.authors}
                                    <br />
                                    <i>{publication.venue}</i>, {publication.year}
                                </div>
                                <div className="publication-icons">
                                    <a href={require(publication.pdf)} target="_blank" rel="noreferrer"><AiFillFilePdf /></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        )
                    })
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    );   
}

export default Publications
```

However, in my console I get an error: [Error] Error: Cannot find module '../../assets/1.pdf'. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you would even want to do that? I would suggest to output an absolute URL to the PDF in the `href` prop. That way the user navigates to the PDF when clicking the link.

Comment: How would I do that? Reacter router doesn't recognize individual pdf file names, so if I define path as "pdf": "/static/media/1.pdf" and use <a href={publication.pdf} target="_blank" rel="noreferrer"><AiFillFilePdf /></a>, I get redirected to 404 page.

Comment: Depending on what your `public` folder looks like, it would be something like `href={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/assets/1.pdf'}`. You'd have to place your PDF files in the `public` folder first for it to work. And if `process.env.PUBLIC_URL` doesn't resolve to the correct URL, then add an `.env` file in your project with the `PUBLIC_URL` variable set to the correct URL. [Documentation](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder).